# How to parse the below JSON response

Tags: android, json

How do I parse the JSON response
The JSON response is as follows

```
{ "status": "SUCCESS", "error_code": "", "message": "", "trips": [ { "trip_id": 405, "arrival_time": "26-12-2016 2:01 pm", "departure_time": "25-12-2016 9:15 am", 

"available_seats": 36, "boarding_points": [ { "bp_address": "SARAI KALE KHAN", "bp_id": "1360160", "bp_name": "SARAI KALE KHAN", "bp_contact_number": "", "bp_landmark": 

"SARAI KALE KHAN", "bp_location": "SARAI KALE KHAN", "bp_prime": "false", "bp_time": "25-12-2016 9:15 am"
}], "dropping_points": [ { "dp_address": "AGRA", "dp_id": "1360186", "dp_name": "AGRA CANTT RAILWAY STATION", "dp_contact_number": "", "dp_landmark": "AGRA", 

"dp_location": "AGRA CANTT RAILWAY STATION", "dp_prime": "false", "dp_time": "26-12-2016 2:01 pm" } ], "cancellation_policy": [ { "from_time": "25-12-2016 8:15 am", 

"to_time": "25-12-2016 9:15 am", "service_charge": "96.25", "seat_fare": 385 }, { "from_time": "24-12-2016 9:15 am", "to_time": "25-12-2016 8:15 am", "service_charge": 

"57.75", "seat_fare": 385 }, { "from_time": 0, "to_time": "24-12-2016 9:15 am", "service_charge": "0.00", "seat_fare": 385 } ], "bus_type": "JAN RATH A/C(2+2)", 

"fare_details": [ { "base_fare": "385.00", "other_tax": "0.00", "self_markup": "0.00", "total_fare": "385.00", "commission": 6.4295
}], "travels_name": "Uttar Pradesh State Road Transport Corporation(UPSRTC)", "operator_id": "11044", "ac": "true", "seater": "true", "sleeper": "false", 

"vehicle_type": "BUS", "partial_cancellation_allowed": "false" } ] }
```

Thanks

Comment: what you tried so far ?

Comment: You can use JSON.parse

Comment: Yes and its done, Thank You

Answer (score 0):

```
JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(Jstring);
String status=jsonObj.getString("status");
String error_code=jsonObj.getString("error_code");
String message=jsonObj.getString("message");
JSONArray trips= jsonObj.getJSONArray("trips");
for (int i = 0; i < trips.length(); i++) {
JSONObject trips_data = trips.getJSONObject(i);
String trip_id=trips_data.getString("trip_id");
String arrival_time=trips_data.getString("arrival_time");
String departure_time=trips_data.getString("departure_time");
String available_seats=trips_data.getString("available_seats");

JSONArray boarding_points=trips_data.getJSONArray("boarding_points");
for (int j = 0; j < available_seats.length(); ++) {
JSONObject boarding_points_data = boarding_points.getJSONObject(i);
String bp_address=boarding_points_data.getString("bp_address");
String bp_id=boarding_points_data.getString("bp_id");
String bp_name=boarding_points_data.getString("bp_name");
String bp_contact_number=boarding_points_data.getString("bp_contact_number");
String bp_landmark=boarding_points_data.getString("bp_landmark");
String bp_location=boarding_points_data.getString("bp_location");
String bp_prime=boarding_points_data.getString("bp_prime");
String bp_time=boarding_points_data.getString("bp_time");
}

JSONArray dropping_points=trips_data.getJSONArray("dropping_points");
for (int j = 0; j < dropping_points.length(); ++) {
JSONObject dropping_points_data = dropping_points.getJSONObject(i);
String dp_address=dropping_points_data.getString("dp_address");
String dp_id=dropping_points_data.getString("dp_id");
String dp_name=dropping_points_data.getString("dp_name");
String dp_contact_number=dropping_points_data.getString("dp_contact_number");
String dp_landmark=dropping_points_data.getString("dp_landmark");
String dp_location=dropping_points_data.getString("dp_location");
String dp_prime=dropping_points_data.getString("dp_prime");
String dp_time=dropping_points_data.getString("dp_time");
}

JSONArray cancellation_policy=trips_data.getJSONArray("cancellation_policy");
for (int j = 0; j < cancellation_policy.length(); ++) {
JSONObject cancellation_policy_data = cancellation_policy.getJSONObject(i);
String from_time=cancellation_policy_data.getString("from_time");
String to_time=cancellation_policy_data.getString("to_time");
String service_charge=cancellation_policy_data.getString("service_charge");
String seat_fare=cancellation_policy_data.getString("seat_fare");

}


JSONArray fare_details=trips_data.getJSONArray("fare_details");
for (int j = 0; j < fare_details.length(); ++) {
JSONObject fare_details_data = fare_details.getJSONObject(i);
String base_fare=fare_details_data.getString("base_fare");
String other_tax=fare_details_data.getString("other_tax");
String self_markup=fare_details_data.getString("self_markup");
String total_fare=fare_details_data.getString("total_fare");
String commission=fare_details_data.getString("commission");
}

String bus_type=trips_data.getString("bus_type");
String travels_name=trips_data.getString("travels_name");
String operator_id=trips_data.getString("operator_id");
String ac=trips_data.getString("ac");
String seater=trips_data.getString("seater");
String sleeper=trips_data.getString("sleeper");
String vehicle_type=trips_data.getString("vehicle_type");
String partial_cancellation_allowed=trips_data.getString("partial_cancellation_allowed");
}
```